# Input Fields Do Not Resize Properly with Browser

Tags: html, css

Ok, when resizing a browser the input fields do not resize properly and will overlap each other in the middle and get distorted before the media script kicks in and sets everything to 100%. The text area width 100% does not line up with the forms. Dealing with this contact form has been exhausting, and I haven't even tried to figure out how to get it to send an email yet lol...

https://p.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/01-07-2017/my_design-demo_Free/528613908/web/index.html

Bonus question: Why does input have to be wrapped in a span or it completely ignores parent divs boundaries??

Per request, here is the JSFIDDLE script. https://jsfiddle.net/LxLux35m/1/

```css
 .Block {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #edeeef;
     padding: 50px 0;
    }
    
    .Block:nth-of-type(odd) {
     background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .Block:After {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     overflow: hidden;
     Zoom: 1;
     height: 0;
    }
    
    .BlockWrapper {
     text-align: center;
     Max-Width: 60%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .BlockSizer1, .BlockSizer2, .BlockSizer3 {
     float: left;
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    .BlockSizer1 {
     Width: 100%;
    }
    
    .BlockSizer2 {
     width: 49%;
    }
    
    .BlockSizer3 {
     width: 33%;
    }
    #ContactForm {
     Padding: 5px;
    }
    
    #ContactForm span {
     width: 49%;
     padding: 5px 0 0 0; 
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #ContactForm > .textarea {
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    #ContactForm > .textarea textarea {
     width: 98%;
     Min-Height: 200px;
     margin: 1em 0 1em 0em;
    }
    
    #ContactForm input {
     width: 92%;
     color: #999999;
     outline: none;
     padding: 10px;
     Border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    }
    
    .ContactFormButton, .ContactFormButton input {
     Width: 100% !important;
    }
    
    @Media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
     div.ContactForm, div.ContactFormRight {
      width: 100%;
      Margin: 5px 0;
      float: none;
      padding: 0;
     }
    }
    
    textarea.ContactForm {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px;
     Min-Height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Block">
  <div class="BlockWrapper">
   <div class="BlockSizer2">
    <form ID="ContactForm" action="#" method="post">
     <h1>Contact Me</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent faucibus massa elit, vitae ultrices libero dapibus nec. Maecenas cursus rutrum odio ut convallis. Curabitur viverra est in diam tincidunt, nec tincidunt tortor dapibus.</p>
     <span><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required="" /></span>
     <span class="ContactFormRight"><input class="" type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Company Name" required="" /></span>
     <span><input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" /></span>
     <span class="ContactFormRight"><input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone" required="" /></span>
     <span class="textarea"><textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message..." required></textarea></span>
     <span class="ContactFormButton"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="BlockSizer2">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: note: your css properties must be all lowercase!

Comment: with an issue like this it would be best to add the code to a jsfiddle.    https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: try to set `#ContactForm span` with `padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px;` and `width: 45%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code just update your media query

```css
<style>
    .Block {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #edeeef;
        padding: 50px 0;
    }

    .Block:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .Block:After {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        Zoom: 1;
        height: 0;
    }

    .BlockWrapper {
        text-align: center;
        Max-Width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .BlockSizer1, .BlockSizer2, .BlockSizer3 {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .BlockSizer1 {
        Width: 100%;
    }

    .BlockSizer2 {
        width: 49%;
    }

    .BlockSizer3 {
        width: 33%;
    }

    #ContactForm {
        Padding: 5px;
    }

    #ContactForm span {
        width: 49%;
        padding: 5px 0 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #ContactForm > .textarea {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #ContactForm > .textarea textarea {
        width: 98%;
        Min-Height: 200px;
        margin: 1em 0 1em 0em;
    }

    #ContactForm input {
        width: 98%;
        color: #999999;
        outline: none;
        padding: 10px;
        Border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    }

    .ContactFormButton, .ContactFormButton input {
        Width: 100% !important;
    }

    textarea.ContactForm {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        Min-Height: 200px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        div.ContactForm, div.ContactFormRight {
            width: 100%;
            Margin: 5px 0;
            float: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .BlockWrapper {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .BlockSizer2 {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #ContactForm span {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }

    }

</style>
```

```html
<div class="Block">
    <div class="BlockWrapper">
        <div class="BlockSizer2">
            <form ID="ContactForm" action="#" method="post">
                <h1>Contact Me</h1>

                <p>Lorem ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent faucibus massa elit, vitae ultrices libero dapibus nec.
                    Maecenas cursus rutrum odio ut convallis. Curabitur viverra est in diam tincidunt, nec tincidunt
                    tortor dapibus.</p>
                <span><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required=""/></span>
                <span class="ContactFormRight"><input class="" type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Company Name"
                                                      required=""/></span>
                <span><input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required=""/></span>
                <span class="ContactFormRight"><input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone" required=""/></span>
                <span class="textarea"><textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message..." required></textarea></span>
                <span class="ContactFormButton"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="BlockSizer2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear in my description on what the problem was. The issue is before the media script kicks in, the forms overlap each other.

Comment: It doesn't look like it unfortunately. The textarea still doesn't have the same fill space as the input fields and don't maintain their spacing.

Comment: check my update answer, i have tested it, just copy this and run

Comment: Still same issue. http://imgur.com/a/layLf there is a screen shot of what it looks like in both firefox and chrome, both updated to latest versions.

Comment: Flawless, now to compare the two to figure out what i was doing wrong :D Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner version, without the span issue :

```css
.Block {
 width : 350px;
 margin : auto;
 margin-top : 25px;
}

#contactform .flex {
 display : flex;
 justify-content : space-between;
 margin-top : 15px;
}

#contactform .flex input {
 width : 47%;
 height : 35px;
 padding : 5px;
}

#contactform textarea {
 width : 100%;
 height : 100px;
 margin-top : 15px;
}

#contactform #submit {
 display : block;
 margin : auto;
 margin-top : 15px;
 width : 100%;
 height : 35px;
 cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Block">

 <h1>Contact Me</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent faucibus massa elit, vitae ultrices libero dapibus nec. Maecenas cursus rutrum odio ut convallis. Curabitur viverra est in diam tincidunt, nec tincidunt tortor dapibus.</p>
 
 <form id="contactform" action="#" method="post">
 
  <div class="flex">
   <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required />
   <input type="text" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Company Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
   <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
   <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone" />
  </div>
  
  <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
  
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 
 </form>
 
</div>
```